# MATLAB error: non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

The following code runs fine and gives the accurate result.

c1...c5 are known constants, and x(1)...x(5) (anonymous vector) are unknown variables which to be fitted by `fminsearch` using the least square method. (t,y) is the given data (curve) to fit the equation, `myfunc` is a `ode45` function saved in a separate .m file.

```
% run the solver
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',10000,'MaxIter',10000,'Display','iter');
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fminsearch(@(x) Obj(x,initial_p,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,t,y),x0,options);

function F = Obj(x,initial_p,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,t,y)
    p = myfunc(x(2:end),initial_p,t,c1,c4);
    yt = mainfunc(x,p,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6);
    F = sqrt(sum((yt-y).^2));
    disp(x);
end

function yt = mainfunc(x,p,c1,c2,c3,c4,~,~)
    yf = c1*c2*c3*c4*sqrt(p);
    yt = x(1)+yf;
end
```

But error occurs (`Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts`) when I rewrite `mainfunc` (all else being same):

```
function yt = mainfunc(x,p,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6)
    ys = c1*c3*(c5/(c6*sqrt(p)));
    yf = c1*c2*c3*c4*sqrt(p);
    yt = x(1)+ys+yf;
end
```

p is a curve (t,p) coming from `ode45` in `myfunc`, it is working fine in the first version of code so no problem there. Is having two terms with sqrt(p) in `mainfunc` causing the problem?

Comment: If `p` is a vector, you probably mean `./` instead of `/`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Should I use `.*` instead of `*` in the assignment for `yf`?

Comment: For scalar multiplication it doesn’t matter. If you are multiplying two vectors element-wise then you do need that. Copy-paste the operations to your command window one by one, and look at what they do and what they produce, make sure that matches your expectation.

Comment: So, for scalar-vector division `./` is necessary, but for scalar-vector multiplication `.*` is not needed? I'm new to Matlab and would like to keep consistency in my code for future reference, hence asking.

Comment: Right. If one of the arguments is a scalar, then `*` and `.*` do the same thing. But that is not true for division. If the right-hand-side argument is a vector/matrix, then you get the matrix (pseudo-)inverse. Multiplication is symmetric (permutes), division is not.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, highly appreciate it.